# Did not receive the Not a cherry hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

Why did I not get the *Not a cherry* hat even though I already done one of the required actions (post, vote, edit or comment)?

Comment: works for me... did you use the app on Stack Overflow or Meta?

Comment: yes, I'm use it on Meta and Stack Overflow

Comment: Stay calm. It might just take some time.

Comment: ok, I'm waiting for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you used the [*official Stack Exchange app*](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/stack-exchange/id871299723) to vote, comment, edit or post a question or answer. And do so on a regular site, not here on Meta (child Meta site activity is not part of the Winter Bash).

Using a mobile web browser or another 3rd party app does not count for the hat.

If you did so, then you also need to be patient. Hats are awarded in batches and it can take a little while before the hat appears.

Comment: It works. I already got my hats!! Thanks